# Sending Ints as bytes from arduino to C# program fails

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, arrays, bit-shift

I'm working on a program in VS2010 C#. It has a GUI that is used to interact with an Arduino over the serial port.

The issue that I'm having is sending a byte value larger than 128(???) from the arduino to the program. I get an integer value on the arduino, break it into highBite and lowByte, and send each one, the reassemble on the other side. 
If I send 600, it will send highByte of 2 and lowByte of 88, and it reassembles to 600 properly via bitshiting <<8 of highByte.

If I try to send 700 which should be 188 and 2, then I am seeing the 188 show in in C# as 63. Why???
A byte should be unsigned on both arduino and C#, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Arduino code (relevant parts): (0x43 signals to C# which data packet it is receiving)

```
byte bytesToSend[3] = {0x43, byte(88), byte(2)}; // 600 broken down to high and low bytes
Serial.write(bytesToSend, 3); // send three bytes
Serial.println(); //send line break to terminate transmission

byte bytesToSend[3] = {0x43, byte(188), byte(2)}; // 700 broken down to high and low bytes
Serial.write(bytesToSend, 3); // send three bytes
Serial.println(); //send line break to terminate transmission
```

C# code: (relevant parts - May have missed a syntax or two since I cut/trimmed and pasted...)

```
string inString = "";
inString = port.ReadLine(); // read a line of data from the serial port
inString = inString.Trim(); //remove newline

byte[] buf = new byte[15]; // reserve space for incoming data
buf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inString); //convert string to byte array I've tried a block copy here, but it didn't work either...

Console.Write("Data received: H: {0}, L: {1}. =", buf[2], buf[1]); //display high and low bytes
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt32((buf[2] << 8) + buf[1])); //display combined value
```

And this is what I get in the serial monitor where it writes out the values:

```
Data received: H: 2, L: 88. = 600
Data received: H: 2, L: 63. = 575
```

The low byte value gets changed or mis-interpreted from 188 to 63 somewhere in the process. What is causing this and how can I fix it? It seems to work fine when the byte value is below 128, but not when it is above.

Comment: Why are you reading the data from the port as *text*? It's not text - it's binary data. (And why are you allocating a 15 byte array and then ignoring it? GetBytes creates a new array.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be problem at your c# side code. You should debug this by printing the string which you are reading just after port.ReadLine(), to see what you are receiving.

Also I would suggest to use C# Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32), so that your data is read into Byte Array which is array of unsigned char. ReadLine() is reading data into string (array of char).

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is wrong. Change the line from:

```
buf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inString);
```

to

```
buf = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(inString);
```

Better yet, when you instantiate your Port object just set the encoder property to this type.

```
...
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
System.Text.Encoding encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
port.Encoding = encoder;
...
```

Remember that ASCII is 7-bit so you will truncate values that are greater than decimal 127. The 1252 encoding is 8 bit and is great for binary data. The table shown [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx) shows the full symbol support for the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Why, in C#, reading full string - which will force you to deal with encodings, ... - and do post-process instead of parsing in time?

```
System.IO.BinaryReader bin_port=new System.IO.BinaryReader(port); //Use binary reader
int b;
int data16;
b=bin_port.ReadByte();
switch (b) {
case 0x43: //Read integer
    data16=bin_port.ReadUInt16();
    while (bin_port.ReadByte()!=0x0a); //Discard all bytes until LF
    break;
}
```